# WordPress - highlighting mixed code in the materials published through the admin panel (php + css + html + js)

Tags: wordpress

Good afternoon. Is there a solution that allows you to frame the piece of code in several languages, and highlight it. Tried several plugins - no one helped.

Note also that wordpress is crazy if tags

```
<? php / * random code * /?>
```

found in the text.

The only plugin that handles more or less, but not highlighted as it should - WP-Syntax It is possible to specify the language in the attributes of the tag, eg

```
<pre lang = "php">
```

But first when inserting the code necessary to embed a lot of pre-tags you can be confusing, and secondly it each tag is separated from the rest of the code and is very torn strange display of code.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to embed complex code in a standard Wordpress editor window is an exercise in frustration. TinyMCE, the Wordpress editor, is configured to strip any unsafe tags from your code. You can [customize TinyMCE](http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE#Customize_TinyMCE_with_Filters) to behave how you want it to, but I think that is less than optimal.

A better solution would be to use a plugin like [Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or build a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) to add some plaintext fields with a language selector for styling your code.